# Can't set Apache encoding to utf-8

Tags: apache, encoding, utf-8

I am having issues with showing a pound sing as a string. If I use `"£"`, it is displayed as `Â£`. If I use `'\u00A3'` it it shown correctly. I can see the http server is serving the page using `content-type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1.`

I have read that adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to the http.conf file solves the problem, but it doesn't for me. The line is present on the file, and I am still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Are you remembering to restart the apache server?  It's not enough to just edit the configuration file.

Comment: @borrible I am, yes.